# Does alternating adding and multiplying primes in sequence produce only 2 prime numbers?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, prime-numbers, recurrence-relations

Define $a_1=2$ and

$$
a_n = \left\{
                \begin{array}{ll}
                  p_na_{n-1}\quad\quad n\quad \text{odd}\\
                  p_n+a_{n-1}\quad n\quad \text{even}\\
                \end{array}
              \right.
$$

where $p_n$ is the nth prime number.  The first few values are $2,5,25,32,352,365,\cdots$.

I've done some research and found that for $n<25$, this sequence produces only 2 primes in this range, $a_1=2$ and $a_2=5$.  Is there a methodology for going about showing whether or not the sequence actually produces no more primes or not?  I realize that $a_{4k-2}$ for $k\in\mathbb{N}$ are the only contenders since the others are either even and/or divisible by $p_i$.  The numbers get very large, so it becomes difficult to check higher values of $n$.

Any thoughts appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You've got the odd/even operation flipped.

Comment: Yes, but 2 is first. I'll add the first values to the question.

Comment: Those first few values suggest the sequence alternates even numbers with multiples of 5. You have already found values that break that pattern, right?

Comment: Correct, that pattern doesn't continue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to my calculation in PARI/GP $$a_{518}$$ is a probable prime with $792$ digits and $$a_{1226}$$ is a probable prime with $2143$ digits.

Comment: Thanks for inspecting. Interesting. What algorithm are you using?